# display column alias from other tbl

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables tbl1 and tbl2 
tbl1 has userid col1 col2 col3 (multiple records per user) 
EDIT tbl2 has userid col4 col5 col6 (Single record per user)
On my original post I had col3 listed here as well which was accident.

tbl2 is used to store custom column names for each user.

now I need to know how do I display this custom column name on results. 
ie how do I reference alias to pull this custom column name for each user.

SELECT 
col1 AS (Dont know what to put here...)

Something like ...col1 AS tbl2.col3 where userid = "testuser" 
How can I accomplish this? 
Maybe somekind of outer/inner query???

Thanks

Comment: Could you name the columns better?  Is col3 identical between the two tables?

Comment: Wow. First of all appreciate all comments :)
I just came here to look if I might have answers 9I was expecting e-mails if there are posts. Anyhow my apologies using col3. It should have tbl2 has col4 col5 col6. I did not have columns or tables created, so I tought to use some generic names. I will try and see if these solutions work. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT tbl2.userid, tb2.col3 AS [your name here], tbl1.col1 AS [your name here], ...
FROM tbl2
INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.userid = tb2.userid
WHERE tbl2.userid = "testuser"
```

The columns themselves are prefixed with the table name (not the alias).  This is only truly necessary when two different tables share a column name, but it's not a bad habit to pick up even in simpler cases.

Comment: OP is trying to alias `col3` as whatever the value of `col6` is, not just trying to alias a column.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT tbl1.col1 as tbl1_col1,tbl2.userid as tbl2_usrid, tbl2.col3 as tbl2_usrid_custcol
FROM tbl1,tbl2
WHERE tbl1.userid = tbl2.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Present on the presentation layer, not the database side:

```
select
    a.userid,
    col1,
    col2,
    a.col3,
    b.col3 as user_col1,
    b.col4 as user_col2,
    b.col5 as user_col3
from
    tblA a
    inner join tblB b on
        a.userid = b.userid
where
    userid='testuser'
```

Then, on the application side, just use `col4`, `col5`, and `col6` as the column names once you go to display the records.

Comment: For the sake of argument, col3 is shared between both tables.  You need to pick one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done either as dynamic SQL (not ideal) or at the presentation layer (greatly preferred).